# Uses deprecated APIs

Tags: google-pagespeed

I hope u are good and healthy, do you how to solve this error?

`Uses deprecated APIs 1 warning found Deprecated APIs will eventually be removed from the browser. Learn more. Deprecation / Warning Source ... https://www.vpn-pink.com:0:-1`

thanks
[image]

I searched this website, didt found the answer, I search google lead me to this website. I guess there is no answer for this bug.

Answer (score 0):

**Delete the following line** from your htaccess or CSP policy

Header set Expect-CT 'enforce, max-age=43200, report-uri=

Comment: Please explain why?

Comment: Me wondering about the same thing: What's the issue? enforce, max-age, or report-uri?